# How style only active class in first ul block

Tags: css, css-selectors

how set color for li.active 2, this is doesn`t work for first-child[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3C89.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do not use images to show code. Instead create a [mcve] and include the code in the question itself using StackSnippets.

Answer (score 0):

first-child pseudo-class doesn't work because these 2 li tags with an active class are children of different parents. You can combine selectors like `.list1 .active` to target the only active element that is somewhere inside list1.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the question but you can select `li.active` in different lists (list1 & list2) in this way. See also https://jsfiddle.net/yezb04L9/

Plz let me kwow if your question is not what I think it is.

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper .list1 li.active {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper .list2 li.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="active">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>4</li>
    <li class="active">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have a lot of ul (dynamic)

Comment: Another approach is `.wrapper ul:nth-child(...) li.active` where dynamicaly your list number is on the three dots (counting from 1)